# Ошибка при запуске Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Возникает ошибка при запуске на kivy. Установлено вроде как всё правильно. Окно вылезает, текст набирается, но при нажатии кнопки всё хорошее заканчивается. Что можно сделать? Код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button 

class FirstApp(App):
    def build(self):
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        self.text_input = TextInput()
        self.label = Label()
        self.button = Button(text = 'ok', on_press = self.click)
        bl.add_widget(self.text_input)
        bl.add_widget(self.label)
        bl.add_widget(self.button)
        return bl
    def click(click, event):
        self.label.text = self.text_input.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    FirstApp().run()
```

Traceback:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте поменять `def click(click, event):` -> `def click(self, click, event):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ правильный дали, но вот вариант для новичка. Рабочий и для понимания проще.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class FirstApp(App):
    def build(self):
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        text_input = TextInput()
        label = Label()

        def click(self):
            label.text = text_input.text

        button = Button(text = 'ok', on_press = click)
        bl.add_widget(text_input)
        bl.add_widget(label)
        bl.add_widget(button)
        return bl


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FirstApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

у всех методов класса первым аргументом идёт `self`

```
def click(self, instance):
    self.label.text = self.text_input.text
```

Comment: Эта ошибка уйдет, но код не будет работать .

Comment: @RomanR готово.

Comment: @Danis Спасибо за помощь